# Замирание окна программы на время выполнения кода

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-code

В c# winforms vs2010 net4.0 есть код (сохранение данных в файл xml). По окончании выполнения этого кода выдается сообщение messagebox.show("выполнено"). Проблема в том, что пока работает код, окно программы некрасиво зависает, пока не появится сообщение messagebox. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать, например, на время выполнения кода визуальную задержку вида окна программы (чтобы окно не дергалось или не замирало как зависшее), при этом возможно с выводом какой-то анимации (анимации типа "подождите"), до тех пор пока не появится итоговое messagebox.show?

Comment: Скорее всего вы запускаете код в ui потоке, потому и зависает. Запускайте сохранение в пуле потоков, а если оттуда надо обновить интерфейс, то используйте диспетчер

Comment: Если не знаете про пул потоков, воспользуйтесь контролом под названием BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 2):

Вам необходимо проводить данную операцию асинхронно, при этом не затрагивать основной поток - так как GUI завязан на основном потоке, и взять какой либо `IdleControl` (крутилка).

Все будет примерно так - вы начинаете в `Task` производить сохранение файла, показываете крутилку и блочите основной UI (`Enabled = false`), по окончанию таски Dispatcher'ом выстреливаете messagebox и убираете крутилку и разлочиваете окно.

Извините меня пожалуйста что описал процесс общими словами.

Comment: Если вы говорите про async/await, то скорее всего оно без плясок недоступно для VS2010 + FW4.0

Comment: @tym32167 а как же просто выплюнуть Task из Task.Factory и ContinueWith ?

Comment: Если вы говорите НЕ про async/await, то может сработать :)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли использование процедуры типа Doevents (как это например в vba excel)?

Comment: @olga это не про то вообще

Comment: Мне хотелось бы даже не ускорять работу (выполняя часть кода не в основном потоке, не обязательно), а на момент выполнения части кода блокировать окно программы (чтобы оно было статичным) и разблокировать (обновить интерфейс) по окончании выполнения кода.